# How to handle duplicated messages in MQTT with qos 1

Tags: mqtt

I am using MQTT with qos 1 which means messages may be sent to client more than once? How can i prevent client from handle same messages twice?

Answer (score 4):

The only way to know for sure if you have received the message twice is to include an ID in the message payload and maintain a list of processed messages in the client.

The PAHO API includes a [isDuplicate()](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttMessage.html#isDuplicate()) (Javascript [version](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/jsdoc/symbols/Paho.MQTT.Message.html#duplicate)) method on received messages, but this is only an indication that the message may be a duplicate, because the original message may never have arrived.